# PDO Mutiple MYSQL statement execute and error log file

Tags: mysql, pdo, php-5.3

Need to execute a set of PDO MYSQl query, incase of any failure after my transaction begins Unable to catch any exception . Even though i gave the table name wrong.
For example

```
class user extends PDO
{
function empid()
{
$dbh->beginTransaction();
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)

try
{
    $update= "update user set data=1 where user_id = 11";
    $update_pre = $dbh->prepare($update);
    $code_pre->execute();

    $insert="insert into user set user name="jesi",age='22';
    $insert_pre = $dbh->prepare($insert);
    $insert_pre->execute();
    dbh->commit

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
$dbh->rollBack();

file_put_contents('mylog.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND); 
}
}
}
```

Any ideas ???

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a number syntax errors which will result in PHP being unable to parse it.

1. You are missing the `;` statement terminator after the call to [`PDO::beginTransaction()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php); also, I *think* that [`PDO::setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) must be called before the PDO object is used (in this case, before that call):

   ```
   $dbh->beginTransaction();
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
   ```

   Therefore, change it instead to:

   ```
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $dbh->beginTransaction();
   ```
2. You name the `UPDATE` PDOStatement object `$update_pre`, but then attempt to invoke the `execute()` method on `$code_pre`:

   ```
       $update_pre = $dbh->prepare($update);
       $code_pre->execute();
   ```

   Therefore, change it instead to:

   ```
       $update_pre = $dbh->prepare($update);
       $update_pre->execute();
   ```
3. You are incorrectly quoting the nested string literals within the `INSERT` SQL:

   ```
       $insert="insert into user set user name="jesi",age='22';
       //  this double quote ends the string --^
       //  and everything thereafter is unparseable
   ```

   Therefore, change it instead to:

   ```
       $insert="insert into user set user name='jesi',age='22'";
   ```

   NB: One normally *shouldn't* quote numeric literals as strings; and furthermore, one *should* use paremeterised queries if those literals are to be substituted from application variables.
4. In attempting to commit the transaction, you have omitted the `$` variable identifier (from the reference to the `dbh` object), the `()` argument parentheses for the method call and the `;` statement terminator:

   ```
       dbh->commit
   ```

   Therefore, change it instead to:

   ```
       $dbh->commit();
   ```